# Get current URL inside custom button

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I have a custom button `uploadImages.blade.php`:

```
@if ($crud->hasAccess('update'))
    <a href="{{ Request::url().'/'.$entry->getKey() }}/images" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> {{ trans('backpack::crud.upload_images_to_photogallery') }}</a>
@endif
```

My current url as shown in the browser is `http://mydomain.eu/backpack/public/folder`

However, `{{ Request::url() }}` (as called from inside the custom view) produces `http://mydomain.eu/backpack/public/folder/search`.

**I have absolutely no idea where that `search` comes from.**

In fact, when I use `{{ Request::url() }}` anywhere else in my code, it produces the right url, but not inside my custom button view.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code that loads this button? Is it done using ajax?

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping. This is the code that loads my button inside the `setup` function of my CrudController: `$this->crud->addButtonFromView('line', 'uploadImages', 'uploadImages', 'beginning');`. I must admit that I don't exactly understand the first "line" parameter tho...

Comment: have you tried using `url()->current()`?

Comment: Yep, `url()->current()` produces the exact same result: `http://mydomain.eu/backpack/public/folder/search`

Comment: I think it has something to do with backpack's search functionality - looks to me like `search` is appended to allow the ajax-driven search box to work.

Comment: Alright, weird, I checked the default buttons which come with backpack, and _nowhere_ do they use `url->current()` or `Request::url()`. To get the actual route, unlike what the documentation states, `{{ url($crud->route) }}` is used and it is working. For some reason, "search" isn't appended here. So the documentation is WRONG, and this is making me bit nervous.

Answer (score 1):

The (wrong) documentation uses the following example for a custom button:

```
@if ($crud->hasAccess('update'))
    <a href="{{ Request::url().'/'.$entry->getKey() }}/moderate" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Moderate</a>
@endif
```

You can see that the current URL should be extracted using `Request::url() which does not work because it appends a "search" parameter to the complete url.

BUT the default buttons that come with backpack do **NOT** use `Request::url()` to get the actual url, but:

`{{ url($crud->route.'/'.$entry->getKey()) }}`

So - as opposed to the documentation - you have to use `url($crud->route)` to get the current URL.

So either I didn't understand something correctly, or the docs are not really trustworthy, which sucks.

Comment: You're totally right, thank you @Adrenaxus - I've just update the docs with the correct URL. The ```Request::url()``` method _used to work_, back when we had non-ajax results. That's why the docs use it. But now it no longer works, since buttons are pulled in using AJAX, the request is actually the AJAX request, instead of the ListEntries request. Thanks for posting your solution, hope the updated docs save others some frustration. Cheers!

Comment: @tabacitu Thank you. I appreciate that you updated the docs on that matter and am glad I could contribute in some way! Please pardon my harshness, I was a bit frustrated back then. Keep up the awesome work over at backpack, cheers!: :-)